# How to access "type" properties of an optional property?

Tags: typescript

See code snippet below:

```js
interface MyObj {
  myOptionalProp: MyOptionalPropObj;  // NOT OPTIONAL
} 

interface MyOptionalPropObj {
  myProp1: SomeType;
  myProp2?: SomeType;
}

type Test1 = MyObj['myOptionalProp']['myProp1'];  // Works
type Test2 = MyObj['myOptionalProp']['myProp2'];  // Works
```

Accessing the nested properties in `MyObj` that are to be assigned to `Test1` and `Test2` works fine if `myOptionalProp` is not optional.

However. once `myOptionalProp` is optional:

```js
interface MyObj {
  myOptionalProp?: MyOptionalPropObj; // OPTIONAL
} 

interface MyOptionalPropObj {
  myProp1: SomeType;
  myProp2?: SomeType;
}

type Test1 = MyObj['myOptionalProp']['myProp1'];  // Doesn't work
type Test2 = MyObj['myOptionalProp']['myProp2'];  // Doesn't work
```

TypeScript throws this error:

```
Property 'myProp1' does not exist on type 'MyOptionalPropObj | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

Is there a way to assert when accessing types? Like an equivalent of

```
myObj.myOptionalProp!.myProp1
```

but for `type`s?

---

The `MyObj` type in this example is auto-generated in our situation, specifically GraphQL Code Generator, and we have no control how it's structured. We could've simply used the type `SomeType` directly but that's currently not an option.

An auto-generated type example would be:

```js
export type TestQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { profile: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'Profile' }
    & Pick<Profile, 'id' | 'name' | 'updatedAt' | 'createdAt'>
    & { owner: Maybe<(
      { __typename?: 'User' }
      & Pick<User, 'id' | 'displayName'>
    )>, users: Maybe<Array<(
      { __typename?: 'User' }
      & Pick<User, 'id' | 'displayName'>
    )>> }
  )> }
);
```

In this example, we cannot access `owner` property of `profile` because owner can be undefined.

```
TestQuery['profile']['owner'] // Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a property is optional, its type is union-ed with undefined, and since only common properties of unions are accessible,  all properties of the original type become inaccessible.

You need to remove `undefined` from the union. The predefined conditional type `Exclude` will do the trick:

```
interface MyObj {
    myOptionalProp?: MyOptionalPropObj; // OPTIONAL
}

interface MyOptionalPropObj {
    myProp1: string;
    myProp2?: number;
}

type Test1 = Exclude<MyObj['myOptionalProp'], undefined>['myProp1']; //ok
type Test2 = Exclude<MyObj['myOptionalProp'], undefined>['myProp2'];  // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=76&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwChlTkBbLABzGAHsQ4AbABSjqoH4AuNa2hszYccuANzIA9JOSYWAFQCSmAHIBBADJEAvkSKhIsRCgyYa9Rq3ZVRhEmUrCqARl4BnMFFABzMfdKO1gBMPMggAK7k2NB+ukRg6FQo8hAezsgAvMgAogAeCEzhACYQADymeADaAOSUZgKWTtUAugA0yOEgJTCgEEUAfDWBHM4tEtJ0ANbxicmpYEGZOfmFJeVYVbX8FkLWLe2d3b0DQ+hOQWOk0shTQA)

Comment: Seems like this can look ugly if we start digging down further but does the job. Are there alternatives?

Comment: Create some `DeepRequired` type to remove the `null` and `undefined` from all properties ? Create some helper `type KeyOf<T, K extends Exclude<T, null | undefined>>  = Exclude<T, null | undefined>[K]` ? There are several ways you could simplify it I guess..

Comment: Thanks! This is what we were looking for. It will work for now.

Comment: @ZeferiniX yes, you can use `NonNullabel<MyObj['myOptionalProp']>` too.